# "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unsupported Marionette protocol version 2" error coming while running my Selenium Script with Gecko Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I have just started learning `Selenium` `Java` . I am running my script with `Selenium Beta 3` and `Mozilla Firefox v43`. Here is my code`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class RegistrationFirefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    
        driver.close();
    }    
}
```

Initially I was getting the error regarding

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver

After installing the `geckodriver` this is the error I am getting (code mentioned above)

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unsupported Marionette protocol version 2, required 3 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 5.26 seconds

Answer (score 4):

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver

Actually `Selenium 3` supports to work with [`Mozilla Firefox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) using [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) executable just like other driver support. That's why you're getting this exception.

To resolve this issue you need to set this executable [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) into system property with `webdriver.gecko.driver` **which you have already done.**

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unsupported Marionette protocol version 2, required 3 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 5.26 seconds

Now the problem is your `Mozilla` version. Actually executable [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) supports [`Mozilla Firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) that's why you're getting this exception.

**To resolve this issue you need to upgrade your [`Mozilla Firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) as well.**